# Required a Cloud Formation template for setting up a Database Migration Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I am trying to build a Cloud Formation template to automate the Database Migration (RDS) and replication using DMS (For backup and DR purpose) across different accounts in AWS Cloud.

I have tested the complete setup manually and it seems to be working fine in the pre-prod environment. However, I would need to automate it before I can get it to the production environment.

So, could someone please share a CF template (I can further customise it according to the requirements) for DMS which can also create all the required resources in Database Migration Service (DMS) including RDS, Replication Instances, Endpoints and Tasks.